# Simplify code: height and width of an 2d-array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

Hello I have a question of how to get a simplified code of the height en the width of an 2D-array i understood you could use bss[0].length and bss.length whenever i tried this i would get that length is no function so i came up with this. Also i would need to compare the length of these array to see if they are equal so [[true,false][true,false]] is valid but [[true,false][true]] would be invalid

```
function size(bss) {
    let row_count = bss.length;
    let row_sizes = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < row_count; i++){
        row_sizes.push(bss[i].length)
    }

    if (Math.min.apply(null, row_sizes) === 0 || Math.min.apply(null, row_sizes) === Infinity){
        return "invalid";
    }
    return {"width":Math.min.apply(null, row_sizes), "height" : row_count };
}
```

Input : [[true,false][false,true]] return width : 2 and height : 2
Input : [[true,false][true]] return "invalid"

Comment: "*i would get that length is no function*" - that sounds like you did `.length()` instead of `.length`?

Comment: I did  ```bss[0].length``` this does give me that error

Comment: really unclear what you're aiming for.

Comment: @MaxVandeVelde `bss[0].length` should only give you an error when `bss.length == 0`, but that's an invalid array anyway according to your definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const valid1 = [ // valid elements
  [3, 2],
  [3, 2]
]
const invalid1 = [ // different sizes
  [1, 2],
  [1]
]
const valid2 = [ // only 1 element
  [1, 2]
]

function sizes(bss) {
  // avoid empty array (optional)
  if (!bss.length) {
    return 'invalid'
  }
  // is array same length with other elements
  const isEqualLength = bss.every(function(v) {
    return v.length === bss[bss.length - 1].length
  })
  if (isEqualLength) {
    // get minimal values from each array element
    const minBss = bss.map(function(v) {
      return Math.min.apply(null, v)
    })

    return {
      width: minBss[0],
      height: bss.length
    }
  }
  return 'invalid'
}

// check valid
console.log(sizes(valid1))
// check invalid length of elements of array
console.log(sizes(invalid1))
// check invalid length of array
console.log(sizes(valid2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify by using `map` instead of that loop, and storing the min/max values in a variable so that you don't need to repeat the `Math` call.

```js
function size(bss) {
    const rowCount = bss.length;
    const rowSizes = bss.map(bs => bs.length);
    const minRow = Math.min(...rowSizes); // using spread syntax instead of apply()
    const maxRow = Math.max(...rowSizes);

    if (minRow != maxRow // ragged array
     || minRow === 0) // zero width
//   || rowCount == 0 // same as minRow === Infinity - both already covered by first condition
        throw new Error("invalid 2d array");
    return {
        "width": minRow,
        "height": rowCount
    };
}

console.log(size([
    [true, false],
    [false, true]
])); // output: {"width": 2, "height": 2}


console.log(size([
    [true, false],
    [false]
])); // throws an error "Uncaught Error: invalid 2d array"
```